# Maintaining Scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, this

I have a general question about maintaining the scope of `this` in an object. Here's a simplified snippet of code. Take note of the `var that = this` line and inside the event handler where I call `that.showMenu()`.

```
var MyObj = {
    init : function(target){
        this.$Target = $(target);
        this.$Menu = $(target).find('.menu');
        this.eventBindings();
    },
    eventBindings : function(){
        var that = this;
        this.$Target.on('click', '.anchor', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            that.showMenu();
            //some other code
        });
    },
    showMenu : function(){
        this.$Menu.show();
    }
};
MyObj.init('.myTarget')
```

Code should be somewhat self explanatory. Typically I try to create reusable methods outside of my `eventBindings()`. The problem I continually run into is passing through `this` which would refer to `MyObj` into the event handler so I can call `this.showMenu()`.

To overcome the obstacle I always assign `this` to a variable called `that` so when I'm further down the scope I have a reference. But I feel like this can't be the best method... can someone suggest a better alternative?

Comment: It looks fine to me, but `that` is a terrible name.  Consider something more descriptive, like `outerScope`.

Comment: Also look into [the `.bind()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) on the Function prototype.

Comment: @RobertHarvey With that reasoning, though, isn't it interesting how `this` came into common usage over the years...? ;)

Comment: @RobertHarvey Not that I agree with him or follow/read him, but Crockford seems to think it's a convention we should use: http://www.crockford.com/javascript/private.html . Although I do use `that` :(

Comment: Ok - thanks guys, I appreciate the info. I came into JS via jQuery so I always tend to second-guess my approaches and defer to someone who may know a bit more.

Comment: Argh.  `this = that`.  It just feels wrong, somehow.

Comment: jquery provides a [method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) exactly for this kind of thing. No need to fiddle with `this`, `that` or whatever.

Comment: @thg435 What method are you referring to?

Comment: @Syon jQuery's [`proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) function

Comment: If `that` sounds ugly.. use `me`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is the best method. In Javascript `this` is scoped dynamically (binding depends on stack, that is on the place from where the function was called), all the other variables - are scoped statically (binding depends on static placement of variable in your code).

And since Javascript treats `this` in a special way, don't feel bad about treating it in a special way too.

You could encapsulate what you are doing now in a function - many libraries provide such a facility, it is usually called "bind". But this will not change what really happens, only hide it (and use up some resources while doing this). Such function could look a bit like:

```
function whatever (functionToProcess, thisToFreeze) { 
   return function() {
       functionToProcess.apply(thisToFreeze, arguments); // apply is built in
   }
}
```

Comment: Awesome - thanks for the information. I'll look into the binding a bit more but general consensus is that the method I use is acceptable, so I wont try to stress over it too much.

Answer (score 0):

Further to @Pointy's comment, using `Function.prototype.bind`:

```
    onClick: function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        this.showMenu();
        //some other code
    },
    eventBindings : function(){
        this.$Target.on('click', '.anchor', this.onClick.bind(this));
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pass it in as event data:

```
this.$Target.on('click', '.anchor', {obj:this}, function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.data.obj.showMenu();
    //some other code
});
```

or store it on the element, but neither are really any different that declaring another variable outside like you are.